# Dashing fails silent on start up, how can I find out more information?

Tags: ruby, windows, thin, dashing

I have installed [dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) and set up a on a windows 8 machine, when I run

```
>dashing start
```

and navigate to `http://localhost:3030`, chrome cannot load the page.

If I navigate to the directory I have dashing installed and start up a [thin webserver](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) by calling

```
>thin start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3030
```

I'm able to get the site started and it returns `Using rack adapter`, but this is just hosting the site, not running dashing.

How can I find some diagnostic information about the dashing startup?

Comment: There's nothing being printed to cmd or powershell, and `> dashing start > c:\temp\output.txt` creates an empty file. So it doesn't get to the point of any output.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old post, but did you find a solution to this? I have a similar silent start up when using dashing on an openSUSE Linux box. When I type dashing start nothing happens and I can't access the page

Comment: @Mark, sorry, this was two jobs ago and I don't have access to the environment. It worked on particular machines, but that's all I remember.

Comment: No problems - thanks for replying. I'll keep trying to figure it out. It's difficult to track down with no errors showing

Answer (score 1):

Some issues in the Dashing repo suggest using a different webserver, such as Webrick or Puma.

See  [Browser Support on Windows 7](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/193) ,
[Widgets not animating in Windows 7](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/256) .

Are there any errors in the java console?  The sample app fails silently for me on OSX when viewing with Chrome, with an error of "Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: \"\xE2\" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8\n  (in my_project_dir/widgets/comments/comments.coffee)" , which turned out to be the left and right quotation marks in comments.coffee.